# If $C$ normal then $Cx=0 \iff C^\dagger x = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose that $C$ is a normal $n\times n$ matrix and $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$. Then
> $$Cx=0\iff C^{\dagger} x=0.$$

I am asked to prove the above. When $C$ is invertible, the question is easy, $$Cx=0\iff C^\dagger Cx=0 \iff CC^\dagger x=0\iff C^\dagger x=0$$

But when $C$ isn't invertible, the leftmost and rightmost equivalences break and I can't really see how to get around. To make life easier we can say if $Cx=0 \implies C^\dagger x=0$ then we can set $C'=C^\dagger$ and repeat the proof for $C'$. So $$Cx=0\\\implies C^\dagger Cx=0\\\implies C(C^\dagger x)=0\\ \iff C^\dagger x\in \ker C$$

Thats the best I can do.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [the pseudoinverse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) which I believe exists for any matrix

Comment: A general note: the adjoint greatly depends on the inner product in question. So, if you have a proof that wants to relate $C$ and $C^\dagger$, you would have to use the inner product/norm.

Comment: We have $\lVert Cx \rVert^2 = (Cx, Cx) = (C^*Cx, x) = (CC^*x, x) = (C^*x, C^*x) = \lVert C^*x \rVert^2$, which implies the claim. Another way to see the above is that in orthonormal eigencoordinates of $C$, $C^*x$ is the complex conjugate of $Cx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** To prove that $Cx=0$ (assuming $C^{\dagger} x=0$), it is much easier to instead show that $\|C x\|^2=(Cx)^{\dagger} (Cx)=0$. To prove that $C^{\dagger} x=0$ (given that $Cx=0$), show that $\|C^{\dagger} x\|^2=0$.

---

**Sidenote:** Your question is a special case of the following more general statement:  A $n\times n$ matrix $C$ is normal if and only if
$$\|Cx\|=\|C^{\dagger} x\|$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Got it thanks $.$